# changing direction from ltr to rtl

Tags: css, direction

How are you ? I bought this template ( http://www.awerest.com/demo/syndicate/onepage/ ) and its very good but I am having a problem . I want to change the direction for the whole template to "rtl" . But its not working infact all of the changes are not being reflected at all .

I added this CSS but its not working also

```
html { direction:rtl;} body { direction: rtl     } section {    direction:rtl; } div {    direction:rtl;} ul     direction:rtl;}
```

If someone can help me what to do to change this template direction that would be good , thanks alot.

Comment: You're missing a `{` after `ul`.  Is that your exact css?

Comment: Add `unicode-bidi: embed` to HTML. You don't need the direction attribute on every element, just do it on html. You can also add the following attribute to the `html` node: `dir="rtl"` instead of modifying the CSS.

Comment: James no problem in the css this is just my writing here . Mohammed I added it..its not working.

Comment: Show us an example of an actual page you have created and explain in which way `direction: rtl` does not work. (What did you expect? What actually happens?)

Comment: Hello Jupa , I've given the url in the question , you can open it in internet explorer and modify anything..tell me what to modify so the direction changes

Answer (score 5):

***SIMPLE SOLUTION***

Use **dir="auto"** on forms and inserted text in order to automatically detect the direction of content supplied at run-time

```html
<div dir="auto">Hello, world!</div>
<br/>
<div dir="auto">لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله</div>
<br/>
<input type="text" dir="auto" value="Hello, world!" > 
<br/><br/>
<input type="text" dir="auto" value="لا إله إلا الله محمد رسول الله" >
```

JSFIDDLE Demo 
https://jsfiddle.net/80k0drsf/

Answer (score 1):

Simple add a `* {direction: rtl}` to your css. If the direction is explicit set at other elements, use `* {direction: rtl !important}`

Comment: I tried , still not working . I can see the elements getting the style on developer tools on IE but its not working . Unchecking/checking the style even doesnt give any effect.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably be better off setting the direction directly in the HTML (using the `dir` attribute) instead of modifying the CSS. That will change all the elements on the page without requiring detailed modifications to the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

To change language automatically dependeing on selected language use following code:

```
<?php
$language = str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale());
if ($language == 'ar') {
    $textdir = 'rtl';
} else {
    $textdir = 'ltr';
}
?>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}" dir="<?php echo $textdir; ?>">
...
</html>
```